# Java integer division result as double?

Tags: java, integer-division

I currently have this code:

```
    int kills = 1;
    int deaths = 2;

    double kdr = 0;

    if(kills > 0 && deaths == 0) {
        kdr = kills;
    } else if(kills > 0 && deaths > 0){
        kdr = kills/deaths;
    }

    System.out.println(kdr);
```

You can test it [here](http://ideone.com/e.js/iHnte1).

**Why is the output 0.00 and not 0.5?**

Comment: This is a duplicate of many things. Just because you're assigning the result of an operation to a `double` doesn't make the operation itself get performed using `double` arithmetic...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `kills/deaths` < 1, you get `0`, since the output of integer division is integer. This `0` is then cast to `0.0` to fit the `double` variable in which you store it.

In order to get a non-integer result, you have to cast one of the numbers to double :

```
 kdr = (double)kills/deaths;
```

Comment: Thank you. I should've tried that, i just assumed that dividing under a double would not need a cast.

Comment: @ThatGuy343 Your division is performed on two integers, and therefore results in integer, and only the result is cast to double, to fit your kdr variable.

Answer (score 1):

Because your input values are integer. if you cast one oy them to a double youget the expected result:

```
 kdr = (double)kills/deaths;
```